# Increment a number in a string and zero fill it

Tags: regex, vb.net, string

In VB.NET, I would like to increment a number in a string and have it zeroed filled.

Here is the sample string with the 5 digit number:
**R00099**

What I would like returned after incrementing it by one:
**R00100**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No need for `PadLeft`:

```
Dim result = String.Format("R{0:D5}", number)
```

The `D5` part in the formatter will format the number as a decimal number, using a fixed number of five digits, and filling the redundant digits with zeros.

More information can be found on the MSDN article about the [decimal format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#DFormatString).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming (with the regex tag) that you want to strip the number out first, and the input will always be in the form of letters followed by numeric then:

```
Function Increment(ByVal prefixedNumber As String) As String
    Dim result As String = String.Empty
    Dim numericRegex As New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^(\D*)(\d*)")
    Dim numericMatch As Text.RegularExpressions.Match = numericRegex.Match(prefixedNumber)

    If numericMatch.Success Then
        Dim number As Integer

        If Integer.TryParse(numericMatch.Groups(2).Value, number) Then
            result = String.Format("{0}{1:D5}", numericMatch.Groups(1).Value, number + 1)
        Else
            ' throw a non parse exception.
        End If
    Else
        ' throw a non match exception.
    End If

    Return result
End Function
```

Have a look at the [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c75he57e%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and [Integer.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) documentation

Answer (score 1):

If the strings have been validated and are in the form specified then this should work

```
Private Function add1ToStringNoChecking(theString As String) As String
    'assumes many things about the input instring
    Return String.Format("{0}{1:d5}", _
                                        "R", _
                                        CInt(theString.Substring(theString.Length - 5, 5)) + 1)
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, _
                          e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim testS As String = "R00009"
    Debug.WriteLine(add1ToStringNoChecking(testS))
End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a handy function to accomplish the OP requirement:

```
    Public Function Counter(ByVal StartingNumber As Int32, ByVal IncrementValue As Int32, ByVal TotalNumberLength As Int32, ByVal Prefix As String) As String
        Dim Temp As Int32 = StartingNumber + IncrementValue
        Dim Temp2 As String = CStr(Temp)

Line50:
        If Temp2.Length < TotalNumberLength Then
            Temp2 = "0" & Temp2
            GoTo Line50
        ElseIf Temp2.Length = TotalNumberLength Then
            'do nothing
        Else
            'means error
            Throw New System.Exception()
        End If

        Return Prefix & Temp2

    End Function
```

Example of using the function:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'now test the function
    MessageBox.Show(Counter(99, 1, 5, "R"))

    'it will show R00100    
End Sub
```

**NOTE:** This solution has been tested OK with Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: -1: GoTo and Throwing an exception with no message? Pretty bad.